# Prevent Notepad++ from reading the entire string as a Regular Expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

**Short story:**
Is there a way to prevent Notepad++ from interpreting all parts of a string as regex?

**The long story:**
I have a list of German cities. In Germany some cities have the suffix `a.d.` (meaning close by) plus the name of a river to differentiate this city from others with the same name.
Unfortunately the suffix is written in various forms, for example:

```
Dillingen a. d. Donau
Dörnfeld a. d.Ilm
Eldena a.d.Elde
Limburg a d Lahn
```

To be able to join this list with other data I need a coherent form, for example:

```
Dillingen a.d. Donau
Dörnfeld a.d. Ilm
Eldena a.d. Elde
Limburg a.d. Lahn
```

I tried to search for

```
(a.d.)\b.+\b
```

but, of course, Notepad++ interprets `a.d.` as regex (. = any letter) giving also results such as

```
Fürstenwalde/Spree
Immenstaad am Bodensee
Jänschwalde Ost
```

making it impossible to search and replace all.
How can I realize this using regex?

I guess the answer is fairly easy but I found no hint in the forum or Notepad++ documentation.

Can someone help? Thanks a lot in advance!

Best,
David

Comment: Escape the dots as `(a\.d\.)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That’s what I’d been looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\ba\s*\.?\s*d\b.+
```

You can use this.`a.d`  here `.` will match any character so `escape it.`See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/7

Comment: Wow great! That’s more than I expected. Thanks a lot for your effort, works perfectly well. +1 if I could…